# Remove Duplicate character from string in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to remove duplicate characters from strings in MongoDB.
Example:
Input string: xxxyzzxcdv
Output string: xyzcdv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- reduce on range(count string)
- keep 2 values  `{"previous": [], "string": ""}` (initial value of reduce)
- get the cur-char `{"$substrCP": ["$mystring", "$$this", 1]}`
  this is the current index on the string, and i take the next char
- if it is in previous kep `"string"` as it is, else `concat` to add the new character

```
heelo

reduce on (0 1 2 3 4) `{"$range": [0, {"$strLenCP": "$mystring"}]}`
we start from  `{"previous": [], "string": ""}`

- get 1 character start from index 0  
 `{"$substrCP": ["$mystring", "$$this", 1]}}`  = "h"
- if this character is on previous don't add it  
 `{"$in": ["$$cur_char", "$$value.previous"]}`
- else add it on previous and on the string the 2 concats in code

Repeat for `index($$this)`= 1
- get 1 character start from index 1  
 `{"$substrCP": ["$mystring", "$$this", 1]}}` = "e"
.....
```

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49e1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"mystring": 
     {"$getField": 
       {"field": "string",
        "input": 
         {"$reduce": 
           {"input": {"$range": [0, {"$strLenCP": "$mystring"}]},
            "initialValue": {"previous": [], "string": ""},
            "in": 
             {"$let": 
               {"vars": {"cur_char": {"$substrCP": ["$mystring", "$$this", 1]}},
                "in": 
                {"$cond": 
                  [{"$in": ["$$cur_char", "$$value.previous"]},
                   "$$value",
                   {"previous": 
                     {"$concatArrays": ["$$value.previous", ["$$cur_char"]]},
                   "string": 
                   {"$concat": ["$$value.string", "$$cur_char"]}}]}}}}}}}}}])
```

---

**Edit**

The second query removed only the duplicates we choose.

Query

- removes only the characters in the array, here only ["x"]
- i removed the `$getField` because its only for MongoDB 5 +

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"mystring": 
      {"$reduce": 
        {"input": {"$range": [0, {"$strLenCP": "$mystring"}]},
          "initialValue": {"previous": [], "string": ""},
          "in": 
          {"$let": 
            {"vars": {"cur_char": {"$substrCP": ["$mystring", "$$this", 1]}},
              "in": 
              {"$cond": 
                [{"$and": 
                    [{"$in": ["$$cur_char", "$$value.previous"]},
                      {"$in": ["$$cur_char", ["x"]]}]},
                  "$$value",
                  {"previous": 
                    {"$concatArrays": ["$$value.previous", ["$$cur_char"]]},
                    "string": 
                    {"$concat": ["$$value.string", "$$cur_char"]}}]}}}}}}},
  {"$set": {"mystring": "$mystring.string"}}])
```

---

**Edit**

If you need to use this aggregation for update, you can use it as pipeline update like.

```js
update({},
[{"$set": ......])
```

See your driver to find how to do update with pipeline, in Java its like above, alternative run it as [database command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/)

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: added one example and explained how it works, i also added one query where we can choose which characters to remove if duplicate

Comment: I am getting the error "Unrecognized expression '$getField'".

Comment: ok i removed the `$getField` for that you need MongoDB 5 you probably have older version, but works without it also.

Comment: one last thing would like to ask is how I can update the main table permanently. Aggregation gives desired output but is not updated in the main table.

Comment: i update the answer, just put this pipeline into an update.(requires MongoDB >=4.2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have the following collection and the records inside of it:

```js
db.messages.insertMany([
    {
        "message": "heelllo theeere"
    },
    {
        "message": "may thhhee forrrce be wiithh yyouuu"
    },
    {
        "message": "execute orrrrdder 66"
    }
])
```

*Due to uncertainty, I am dropping solutions for both **manipulating while querying** and **updating the records (permanently)**.*

#### If you want to remove them while running your aggregation query:

In addition to @Takis's solution, using `$function` pipeline operator can be another option if your MongoDB version is 4.4 or higher.

[Further readings on $function operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/function/)

```js
// Query via Aggregation Framework
db.messages.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            message: {
                $ne: null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            distinctChars: {
                $function: {
                    body: function (message) {
                        return message
                            .split("")
                            .filter(function (item, pos, self) {
                                return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
                            })
                            .join("");
                    },
                    args: ["$message"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
])
```

#### If you want to remove them via an update operation:

```js
// Update each document using cursor
db.messages.find({ message: { $ne: null } })
    .forEach(doc => {
        var distinctChars = doc.message
            .split("")
            .filter(function (item, pos, self) {
                return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
            })
            .join("");

        db.messages.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, [{ $set: { distinctChars: distinctChars } }]);
    });
```

***A quick reminder**: Above script just shows an easy way to update the records to reach the goal without focusing on other details. It can be an expensive operation depending on your real world collection's size and configurations, sharding for instance. Consider to improve it with your own way.*

#### Result

For both way, the result should be like the following:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "618d95ccdedc26d80875b75a"
    },
    "message": "heelllo theeere",
    "distinctChars": "helo tr"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "618d95ccdedc26d80875b75b"
    },
    "message": "may thhhee forrrce be wiithh yyouuu",
    "distinctChars": "may theforcbwiu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "618d95ccdedc26d80875b75c"
    },
    "message": "execute orrrrdder 66",
    "distinctChars": "excut ord6"
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there any way by which we can eliminate for loop in the second approach?  And one more thing can we go with input from the user Like if a user chooses "E" from "heeellllloooo". Then we will eliminate only "E" and the end result will be "helllloooo".